# Invalid SQL statement in VBA, Word form fields to Access db

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I get an Invalid SQL statment error, when running this piece of code.

I got the code from here [Word Forms to Acces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155434(v=office.10).aspx) where i have updated pieces to make it work for me.

My problem is where in my code shall i add the SQL statement to make it work correctly.

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strDocName As String
Dim blnQuitWord As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

strDocName = C:\Word file

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(strDocName)

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=N:\Direction\4-Signalliste\" & _
"Signal_liste.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234"

rst.Open "Order", cnn, _
adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

With rst
.AddNew
!CompanyID = doc.FormFields("CompanyID").Result
!swgNr = doc.FormFields("SWGNr").Result
!SWG_typical = doc.FormFields("SWG_typical").Result
!Signal_niveau = doc.FormFields("Signal_niveau").Result
!protocol = doc.FormFields("Protocol").Result
!Baud_rate = doc.FormFields("Baud_Rate").Result
!casdu = doc.FormFields("CASDU").Result
!casdu1 = doc.FormFields("CASDU1").Result
!casdu2 = doc.FormFields("CASDU2").Result
!IP_A = doc.FormFields("IP_A").Result
!IP_B = doc.FormFields("IP_B").Result
!IP = doc.FormFields("IP").Result
!gate = doc.FormFields("Gate").Result
!Subnet = doc.FormFields("Subnet").Result
!Link_addr = doc.FormFields("Link_addr").Result
.Update
.Close
End With
doc.Close
If blnQuitWord Then appWord.Quit
cnn.Close
MsgBox "Data Imported!"

Cleanup:
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
Select Case Err
Case -2147022986, 429
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
blnQuitWord = True
Resume Next
Case 5121, 5174
MsgBox "You must select a valid Word document. " _
    & "No data imported.", vbOKOnly, _
    "Document Not Found"
Case 5941
MsgBox "The document you selected does not " _
    & "contain the required form fields. " _
    & "No data imported.", vbOKOnly, _
    "Fields Not Found"
Case Else
MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
End Select
GoTo Cleanup

End Sub
```

Comment: Show the full error.

Comment: "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a similar situation in my PC and this code worked (just change connection, table name, and fields):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strDocName As String
Dim blnQuitWord As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=F:\app\test.accdb"

rst.Open "Table1", cnn, _
adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

With rst
.AddNew
!Field1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result
!Field2 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result
!Field3 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result
.Update
.Close
End With
'doc.Close
If blnQuitWord Then appWord.Quit
cnn.Close
MsgBox "Data Imported!"

Cleanup:
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
Select Case Err
Case -2147022986, 429
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
blnQuitWord = True
Resume Next
Case 5121, 5174
MsgBox "You must select a valid Word document. " _
    & "No data imported.", vbOKOnly, _
    "Document Not Found"
Case 5941
MsgBox "The document you selected does not " _
    & "contain the required form fields. " _
    & "No data imported.", vbOKOnly, _
    "Fields Not Found"
Case Else
MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
End Select
GoTo Cleanup

End Sub
```

Comment: I got the same error as before with your changes  "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE' "

Comment: I can send you files (Access and Word) which I used to do this. If you give me an email address I will send you.
Did you add reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects library?

Comment: I got your files to work, I missed the Form Object Library 2.0

Comment: Also I had to make a new table in my own database to make it work without the error still coming up. Why is that?

Comment: I am creating the error again, when opening word from Access @shukri gashi

Comment: Can you send me on my email your files

Comment: I solved it by moving the code from Word into Access